# Airflow set Kubernetes Secret name via templating

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-k8s

In Airflow I would like to access a Kubernetes name based on my trigger conf in order to mount it to a k8s pod via `KubernetesPodOperator`. i.e. here I am looking up the secret called `poc` by default, but maybe I want to look up a different secret based on the trigger conf.

It seems `Secret` cannot take templated values.

```py
from airflow import models
from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import (
    KubernetesPodOperator
)

with models.DAG(
    dag_id="my_k8s_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=YESTERDAY,
    params={
        "SECRET_NAME": "poc",
    },
) as dag:
    env_secrets = [
        Secret(
            deploy_type="env",
            deploy_target=key,
            secret="{{ dag_run.conf['SECRET_NAME'] }}",
            key=key,
        )
        for key in [
            "SECRET_KEY1",
            "SECRET_KEY2",
        ]
    ]
    
    kubernetes_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
        secrets=env_secrets,
        ...
    )
```

Tried accessing the templated value of `SECRET_NAME` in different ways, but couldn't get anything to work.